# Unrecognized selector sent error immediately after successful selector call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.2, selector

This bug is befuddling to me, but here goes:

I was trying to set up an IBAction to run on touch up inside on a UIButton.  For some reason, it wasn't working, and wasn't really giving me any gdb errors.  Every now and then it would mention an unrecognized selector.  I checked to make sure my File's owner was the correct class, and everything was in check and it was, so I ran it again and still nothing.

I figured it might be a problem with Interface Builder, so I used addTarget: on the button, setting the target as self, and the selector the selector of the method I wanted to call, and still got an unrecognized selector error.  To test that the selector did exist, I ran a [self performSelector:] on the selector of the method I wanted, and it worked.  So basically right now I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelector:@selector(hi)];

    [_backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(hi) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)hi {
    NSLog(@"HI");
}
```

The perform selector works perfectly, and logs "HI".  Here's the kicker, when I touchup on _backButton, it gives me an unrecognized selector error, even though I just called it and it worked:

```
2011-10-22 19:54:40.824 VideoGif[396:707] -[NSKeyValueObservance hi]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x590690
2011-10-22 19:54:40.831 VideoGif[396:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKeyValueObservance hi]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x590690'
```

I've taken screen shots of the nib and the implementation file, viewable here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9GsW.jpg

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Is it possible that the instance of CaptionEditorViewController is being deallocated for some reason, and than the pointer (self) is pointing to corrupted memory which happens to be an NSKeyValueObservance?

Comment: I'm using ARC, so in theory that shouldn't happen.  I don't know the ins and outs of ARC well enough though that I could definitely rule that out.

Comment: Actually now that I think about it, the class it thinks it's calling the selector on has changed randomly this whole time, which would suggest what you're talking about.  I'll go read up on ARC and see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I apologize for what probably (not wrongly) seems to be shameless rep-whoring :)

Comment: So it looks like I'd been storing the view of my view controller in an instance variable of it's parent, instead of the view controller itself.  ARC was retaining the view, but mistakenly releasing the view controller since it thought nothing was using it.  Totally wouldn't have gotten that if you hadn't left your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably happening because your instance of CaptionEditorViewController is being deallocated for some reason, as pointed by random classes throwing "unrecognized selector" exceptions

Comment: Repwhore away, you earned it!